# How to execute a "process/function" in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Imagine I have a database table with some columns, `n` columns and `n` rows, and one of that columns is a date (`YY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`)

So I need to take the actual date, I know there is a function called `CURRENT_DATE`.

And I want to do some "logic" with the actual date and the date for every row in the database (there is a column in the table with a date, that one), that logic simply to compare the years and months between them and if the difference between one to the other is `X` months, I will return that row, and if not, I will not return it.

So, simply as return everything in the DB with the condition of that "logic" and which will not accomplish, don't return it.

The problem is, where should I put that logic in a SQL query, I don't think I really can. Can I do what I want with SQL, or it's necessary some type of stuff?

Example Data:

[image]

So if I want that the query only return that rows that the difference between the actual Date and which it's column Date, is less than 3 months for example,
it should return Google, Amazon, Twitter, YouTube and Microsoft

Comment: I think this should be do-able in SQL (specifically, PostgreSQL).  Could you provide a sample data set from which we can try to put together a query for you?

Comment: I don't have access to the database right now, and I don't think I will have authorization for upload that data, but, I can give you some example of my own really quickly

I will edit the post with an image example (and sorry for my English before, I was asleep

Comment: you tagged with `sql-server` but also asked "Can I do what I want with SQL" -- are you confined to a particular database platform?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'm dealing with sql-server, I think I'm limited to that

Comment: maybe you can try this one: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187694/how-does-date-math-work-in-sql-server

Comment: Okey thank you, I'll take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something obvious here, you've just really, really over-complicated a simple `where` clause:

```
SELECT A, B, C -- Please tell me these are not your actual column names!
FROM TableName
WHERE C >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
AND C <= DATEADD(MONTH, 3, GETDATE()) -- Assuming future dates are also in the table
```

Comment: Probably it's simple, I don't usually work with databases so my aknowladge of that is very low, but I need to deal with this. I'll try this info and I'll update the question later. Thank you!